# Is there an attribution obligation for arXiv preprints with the standard license?

Tags: citations, arxiv, license, creative-commons

I'm currently learning more about arXiv's different licenses. One of them is arXiv's [own](https://arxiv.org/licenses/nonexclusive-distrib/1.0/license.html) perpetual, non-exclusive license. Unlike the CC licenses, it does not seem to include any clauses on attribution to the author.

Are scholars under the obligation to cite or attribute to the author of an arXiv preprint when it is under the “standard” arXiv.org non-exclusive license to distribute?

Comment: I am not sure that the arXiv license allows readers to distribute, rather than just arXiv. [This page](https://arxiv.org/help/license) explaining the scope of each license may be relevant, which says "This license gives limited rights to arXiv..." as opposed to "This license allows reusers..." for the CC licenses. I may have interpreted it incorrectly, however.

Comment: Don't confuse copyright with scholarly ethics/norms.  No matter what the license allows you to do _legally_, using someone else's work without giving them credit is plagiarism.

Comment: @JeffE Right, I agree. I'm just curious about this license, because I'm planning on publishing a preprint on the arXiv in the near future myself. I'm still in doubt as to which license I should choose.

Comment: @MaxMuller Related threads: https://academia.stackexchange.com/search?q=choose+arxiv+license

Comment: @GoodDeeds Yup, I've seen some of them. Does any answer this question? If there's a duplicate, this question can be flagged as such.

Comment: I don't think any answer your question as stated, just related, in case you hadn't seen them.

Answer (score 1):

If you use someone else's work, academic honesty requires you to cite that work.  Licenses and copyright are completely irrelevant.

If you redistribute someone else's work, then the license is important.  That is a matter of law, not academic honesty.  The ArXiv license does not permit you to redistribute work unless you are ArXiv; attribution is irrelevant.  The ArXiv license also does not authorize modification, so ArXiv cannot change the author names in a paper.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question. Assuming someone wants to redistribute a paper (so para 2 applies) under the arXiv license, do they need to attribute the author? That may be off-topic, but then I think the question should be closed or migrated.

Comment: @GoodDeeds Is this better?  I am not sure what the asker wants to do, but I guess they want their paper cited in other people's papers.